# passing a string with line break on to a cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a mypage.cshtml as below

```
<p><span>@r.get("My_Message")</span></p>
```

Below is my entry in my resx file

```
<data name="my_message" xml:space="preserve">
<value>This is first line &lt;br/&gt; This is my second line &lt;br/&gt;</value>
</data>
```

When i run mypage.cshtml , my line break char for the above string is not working .
please help

The output I am getting is

```
This is first line <br/> This is my second line <br/>
```

I don't know why lines are not breaking I need an output as below

```
This is first line
This is my second line
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
<p><span>@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(r.get("My_Message")))</span></p>
```